# Python abstract property with method access detection

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, inheritance

I'm translating some Java source code to Python. So I have this abstract Java class which I translate in:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def sampleProp(self):
        return self.sampleProp

    # this one is the important
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def sampleList(self):
        return self.sampleList
```

My doubt is that the child classes in Java all add the elements to the list in the child classes because the list (java.util.List in Java) is already initialized in the parent Java Class as a member.

```
public MyAbstractClass {
    List<Object> sampleList = new ArrayList<Object>();
}

public ChidClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    public ChildClass() {
        sampleList.add("Element 1")
        sampleList.add("Element 2")
    }
}
```

Parent class is lacking a constructor, so if I implement the constructor **init** in Python to initialize the list, I have to probably write super() in all child classes.

I don't know if I should do that. I thought maybe doing something like this would work:

```
class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def sampleList(self):
        if not self.sampleList:
        # Alternative way
        #if not hasattr(self, 'sampleList'):
            self.sampleList = []
        return self.sampleList
```

I'm going to try if this works, but I would like to know alternatives and also which is the best and safest way to do this. I'm looking for the engineering way so if something changes, the consequences in my code will be minimal

Thanks

Comment: The proper way to do this would be to create the list in the constructor. Why are you trying to avoid having a constructor? Any properly implemented child class will call its parent constructor anyway, so it's not like having a constructor results in more effort.

Comment: "Parent class is lacking a constructor,..." If you mean Java, this is not correct. If no constructor is implemented, Java provides a default constructor, setting all attributes to their default values (`0` for primitives, `null` for objects). Note that this will only be done for attributes which are not initialized at declaration. As for `super()`: at least in Java, each class that does not explicitly call another constructor via `this(...)` or `super(...)` calls `super()` implicitly.

Comment: @Rawing If there's no need to write the super() call in every child class, it looks like the way to go. I wasn't sure if this was needed or not

Comment: Calling `super()` in every child class is the way to go. Why would you ever _not_ call a parent class's constructor?

Comment: @Turing85 I knew about that detail of Java classes having default constructors, just wanted to express there was no explicit constructor written in my sample source code. I didn't know if in Python3 the super() call is made anyway.

Comment: @Rawing I finally opted for your solution. You can post your answer if you like so. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create the list in the `__init__` function.

**Any** correctly implemented child class will call its parent class's constructor, regardless of whether that constructor exists or not (i.e. it's the default `object` constructor), so you have no reason to avoid creating an `__init__` method.

```
class MyAbstractClass(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sampleList = []

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def sampleProp(self):
        return self.sampleProp
```

Comment: I'm now curious if the other way would have worked, even knowing it was a worse choice. Maybe it would be useful in another context